# How to access more than one database table data in android?

Tags: android

I need to display data from 4 different database tables in android. Previously for testing I used single table to display data. For that I have created three files.

1)DBAdapter.java

2)UserBO.java

3)Test.java

**DBAdapter.java**

```
    public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static String DB_PATH = "";
        private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase1;
        private final Context myContext1;

        private static DBAdapter mDBConnection;


        private DBAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext1 = context;
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                    + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/";

        }


        public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapterInstance(Context context) {
            if (mDBConnection == null) {
                mDBConnection = new DBAdapter(context);
            }
            return mDBConnection;
        }


        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {
                // do nothing - database already exist
            } else {
                // By calling following method 
                // 1) an empty database will be created into the default system path of your application 
                // 2) than we overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }


        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // database does't exist yet.
            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }


        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
                // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext1.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
                // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
                // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }


        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase1 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);     
        }


        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if (myDataBase1 != null)
                myDataBase1.close();
            super.close();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }


        public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,
                String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,
                String having, String orderBy) {
            return myDataBase1.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,
                    groupBy, having, orderBy);
        }


        public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,
                String whereClase, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,
                String having, String orderBy) {        

            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
              ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
              Cursor cursor = myDataBase1.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClase, whereArgs,
                        groupBy, having, orderBy);        
              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {
                     list = new ArrayList<String>();
                     for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){                   
                         list.add( cursor.getString(i) );
                     }   
                     retList.add(list);
                 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
              }
              if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                 cursor.close();
              }
              return retList;

        }   

        public Cursor selectRecordsFromDB(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {
            return myDataBase1.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);      
        }


        public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectRecordsFromDBList(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {       
              ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
              ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
              Cursor cursor = myDataBase1.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);           
              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {
                     list = new ArrayList<String>();
                     for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){                   
                         list.add( cursor.getString(i) );
                     }   
                     retList.add(list);
                 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
              }
              if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                 cursor.close();
              }
              return retList;
           }

    }

**UserBO.java**
  public class UserBO {
        int sid;
         String sname;
        public int getsid() {
            return sid;
        }
        public void setsid(int sid) {
            this.sid = sid;
        }

        public String getsname() {
            return sname;
        }
        public void setsname(String sname) {
            this.sname= sname;
        }
    }
```

**Test.java**

```
 public class Select extends Activity  {

        private Header header;
        private ListView lvUsers;
        private   ArrayList<UserBO> mListUsers;
        private SharedPreferences mPreferences1;
        private SharedPreferences mPreferences2;
        String   myString1,query;
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            System.out.println("before k select "+k);
            setContentView(R.layout.select);

            header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.layoutHeader);

             mListUsers = getUsers();

            lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_user);
            lvUsers.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, R.id.lv_user, mListUsers));
        }

        public ArrayList<UserBO> getUsers(){                

            DBAdapter dbAdapter=DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
            try {
                dbAdapter.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
            }

             mPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser1", 0); 
           myString1 = mPreferences1.getString("student id",sid);

             dbAdapter.openDataBase();

     **query="SELECT tabel1.*, tabel2.* FROM tabel1, tabel2 WHERE  tabel1.PK=tabel2.FK;";**

         ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
            dbAdapter.close();
            ArrayList<UserBO> usersList = new ArrayList<UserBO>();

            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<String> list = stringList.get(i);
                UserBO user = new UserBO();
                 AppConstants.alConductedQuestions.add(user);
                 System.out.println("mListUsers");
                  System.out.println(user);
                try {
                    user.sid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
                    user.sname = list.get(1);
                } 
                   catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("***" + Test.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
                }
                usersList.add(user);

            }


            return usersList;

        }



        // ***ListAdapter***
        private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserBO> {  // --CloneChangeRequired
            private ArrayList<UserBO> mList;  // --CloneChangeRequired
            private Context mContext;

            public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<UserBO> list) { // --CloneChangeRequired
                super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
                //System.out.println(list);
                this.mList = list;
                this.mContext = context;


            } 

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                View view = convertView;
                try{
                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); 
                    // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
                }
                final UserBO listItem = mList.get(position);    // --CloneChangeRequired                
                if (listItem != null) {
                    // setting list_item views      

                    ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.casedescription) ).setText( listItem.getsid()+"");
                    ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_question) ).setText( listItem.getsname()+"");
                    ArrayList<UserBO> mList1;



                }
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"hii":e.getMessage();
                    Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);  

                }
                return view;



            }
            }
        }
```

In test.java I am writing the query. In UserBO I am writing the setter and getter methods. In DBAdapter file I am mentioning the database name. So here my question is I have 4 tables in my database. So I need to display data using those tables. **Shall I write the setter and getter methods of the column names of all the tables in one single UserBO file?**

Also I am getting the values of each column of single table by giving
**user.sid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
user.sname = list.get(1);**
**How do I get the column names of all the tables?** **I mean shall I need to get all the columns of all the tables in Test.java file?**
Please help me regarding this....I am it confused with this different tables.....
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you have one database & three tables or all three tables are in different databsaes ?